# Why is this function so much faster with filepaths as str then as PosixPath?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pathlib

I just have this function that generates myself a filedict.

Now i noticed it is quite slow and i wanted first to thread it but then i noticed by accident actually that it is way way faster using the filepaths as str then as PosixPath.

I was thinking about it and i don't know is it really so much slower two compare if the Paths are the same then two strings? Or am i missing something out here which just slows down the whole thing with PoxisPaths?

So jobtype, jobname and filetype are strings, and i tried just feeding the function with either a generator putting our the filepath as str or as PoxisPath generated from pathlibs Path.

```py
    def filedictmaker(filesdict, jobtype, jobname, filetype, filepath):
        if jobname in filesdict[jobtype]:
            if filetype in filesdict[jobtype][jobname]:
                if filepath in filesdict[jobtype][jobname][filetype]:
                    pass
                else:
                    filesdict[jobtype][jobname][filetype].append(filepath)
            else:
                filesdict[jobtype][jobname].update({filetype: [filepath]})
        else:
            filesdict[jobtype].update({jobname: {filetype: [filepath]}})
        return filesdict
```

I just thought its gonna be the same, but no its a lot slower, 135s compared to 6s.

I also tried to give str to start with and just convert them when added and then use

```py
if filepath in [str(i) for i in filesdict[jobtype][jobname][filetype]]:
    pass
```

but that just gave me the same runspeed then going in with Paths to start with.

Iam just curious whats the reason for that?:D

P.S i didnt try reversing the if statements and just catch the KeyError, but yeah thats another building place.

Comment: Ok what made it really slow is actually to call the function cause of deepcopy each time i guess:D both is under a second now but still str are faster 0.25 to 0.4.